# Using Leibniz rule to derive power rule

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a $\mathbb{R}$-derivation $d:C^{\infty}([1,2])\rightarrow C^{\infty}([1,2])$. For rational number $\frac{p}{q}$, we know how to derive $d(x^{\frac{p}{q}})=\frac{p}{q}x^{\frac{p}{q}-1}$ using Leibniz rule(product rule). However, if $\eta$ is irrational number, how to derive power law $d(x^{\eta})=\eta x^{\eta-1}$ from Leibniz rule only?